# Empty response from an app created in heroku

Tags: heroku, facebook-apps, heroku-toolbelt

When creating a facebook app and using heroku service. The heroku app is returning an empty response. I have tried creating many apps but all have the same problem. I am using PHP in heroku.[image]

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem I cloned the git repository of my app from heroku, made some changes in some files by adding few random spaces so that they are identified as a different version from the cloned files. Then i pushed the repo back to heroku. Now the app worked fine.[image]

Comment: It would be nice to have a reason given along with down votes. This fix worked for me in 2013, and it is quite possible that it no longer works. It doesn't mean it is/was wrong at the time of posting.